Upper bound of polynomial integral
In my recent research, I encountered the following integral inequality
$$\int_0^1kx^{k-1}(1+x)^{2k+1}\mathrm{d}x<2^{2k},$$
where $k$ is a positive integer. This inequality can be transformed to binomial coefficient form, but the induction method doesn't work.
The following picture gives the value of $RHS-LHS$ for $k\leq500$. So the difference is increasing at speed $10^k$.

I also want to know where can I find some messages about the integral form $\int_0^1x^m(1+x)^n\mathrm{d}x$ ?

Do you know the Gaussian hypergeometric function ?

@Cornman The beta function is $B(m+1,n+1)=\int_0^1x^m(1-x)^n\mathrm{d}x$. It's different.

The simplest way to solve it is by using the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

@Rookie Yes, C-S works well.

Using IBP, we have
$$
 \int_0^1kx^{k-1}(1+x)^{2k+1}\mathrm{d}x
 = 2^{2k+1} - \int_0^1 (2k+1)(1+x)^{2k} x^k \,\mathrm{d} x.
$$
It suffices to prove that
$$\int_0^1kx^{k-1}(1+x)^{2k+1}\mathrm{d}x < \int_0^1 (2k+1)(1+x)^{2k} x^k \,\mathrm{d} x,$$
or
$$\int_0^1 (1+x)^{2k}x^{k-1}[(k+1)x - k]\,\mathrm{d} x > 0,$$
or
$$\int_{k/(k+1)}^1 (1+x)^{2k}x^{k-1}[(k+1)x - k]\,\mathrm{d} x
 > \int_0^{k/(k+1)} (1+x)^{2k}x^{k-1}[k - (k+1)x]\,\mathrm{d} x , \tag{1}$$
which is true since
\begin{align*}
 &\int_{k/(k+1)}^1 (1+k/(k+1))^{2k}x^{k-1}[(k+1)x - k]\,\mathrm{d} x\\[6pt]
 ={}& \int_0^{k/(k+1)} (1+k/(k+1))^{2k}x^{k-1}[k - (k+1)x]\,\mathrm{d} x. \tag{2}
\end{align*}
(Note: Clearly $\mathrm{LHS}_{(1)} > \mathrm{LHS}_{(2)}$,
and $\mathrm{RHS}_{(1)} < \mathrm{RHS}_{(2)}$.
Also, (2) is equivalent to
$\int_0^1 x^{k-1}[(k+1)x - k]\,\mathrm{d}x = 0$
or $\int_0^1 (k+1)x^k \,\mathrm{d} x = \int_0^1 k x^{k-1}\,\mathrm{d} x$ which is clearly true.)
We are done.

$$I_k=\int_0^1k\,x^{k-1}\,(1+x)^{2k+1}\,dx=\, _2F_1(-(2 k+1),k;(k+1);-1)$$ where appears the Gaussian hypergeometric function.
Using numerical heuristics and asymptotic analysis
$$1-\frac 1{8\,k}+\frac 1{16\,k^2}~ <~2^{-2k}\,I_k ~<~1-\frac 1{16\,k}$$

thanks ! But the solution is too hard for me. I accepted another one. Hope you don't mind. Have a nice day~

@Rookie. Why should I mind ? Cheers :-)
